# Unusual representation of array in HTTP response (array : 0x7f7298c057f0)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to send an array to a webpage in an HTTP response from an Electric Imp, and it is being returned in the following string:

`(array : 0x7f7298c057f0)`

Is this an array representation I can decode into the actual array? I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

It is a memory address. The data in the array hasn't been transferred.